# Text alignment inside table using Javascripts

Tags: javascript, java, jtable, alignment, tabular

Can you please tell me how to align text inside the table using Javascripts. I am using jTable to show data.

Here is a picture of my table

[image]

How can I align text right, because my Arabic language need that!

Comment: Do you use java and `JTable` or you use javascript ?

Comment: I am using JTable inside javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

### You can use **CSS** directly on the table

try put this on td tag

```
<td style="text-align:right">...
```

or as a property of the table

```
<table style="text-align:right">....
```

### Or through an external style sheet

```
td{
   text-align:right
}
```

or

```
table{
   text-align:right
}
```

### Update for JTable

Add this on the head of the page

```
<style>
   table{
       tex-align:right
   }
</style>
```

or apply the css on the div that uses JTable to create the table

```
<div id="jtable_id" style="text-align:right"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know jTable? there isn't <td> nor <table> tag. How Can I use these tags ad where? thanks for your help

Comment: add this on your page <style>table{text-align:right}</style> in the head , you'll see that the alignment will be applied to the table

Answer (score 0):

For align text inside `JTable` you can use `TableCellRenderer` instead of javascript code. For example:

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTable t = new JTable(new Object[][]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}, new Object[]{1,2,3});
        t.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                    Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                    int row, int column) {
                Component tableCellRendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus,
                        row, column);
                ((JLabel)tableCellRendererComponent).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
                return tableCellRendererComponent;
            }
        });
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

[image]

Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender).

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to use it. I am using VS 2013, and ASP.NET. thanks again:)